# Is there a way to blend a dark drop-shadow filter to not show up on light(white) backgrounds?

Tags: css

I have a pretty tricky thing I'd like to do and I'm not sure it's possible to do it.

I have a few stacked PNGs with transparent backgrounds that weave in front of and under some dark stripes. I'd like the PNGs to cast a shadow on the dark stripes, but not on the underlying white image.

Here's a screenshot of what I currently have, since I'm under no impression I'll ever be able to properly describe it.

[image]

I'd like the head and scale to keep casting the shadows onto the stripe, but I don't want anything to cast a shadow on the white background.

I know how I'd accomplish this with a box-shadow (abusing before/after), but I'm it a loss with how to do it with a `filter: drop-shadow`. I tried using mix-blend mode and I was able to accomplish the opposite - dropping the shadow *only* on the white background and not on the stripe.

To make it clear - the black stripe is an HTML element and not a part of any of the PNG layers.

EDIT to add code:

HTML (React):

```
<div className="main-section-container">
  <h3 className="main-section-title">About us</h3> {/* This is the stripe */}

  <div className="about-us-image-container">
    <img src={justiceBg} className="justice-bg" />
    <img src={justiceArm} className="justice-arm" />
    <img src={scaleBase} className="justice-scale-base" />
    <img src={scaleLeft} className="justice-scale-left" />
    <img src={scaleRight} className="justice-scale-right" />
  </div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
.main-section-title
  background: $black
  width: 100%

.about-us-image-container
   position: relative
.about-us-image-container > *
   position: absolute
   top: -35%
   right: 40%
   width: 100%
   min-height: 600px
   transform-origin: 26% 19%
   will-change: transform
   filter: drop-shadow(10px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75))

.justice-arm
   z-index: -1
```

Comment: share the code with the PNGs

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the code is since I'd be willing to modify it as needed. Essentially the image of the sculpture is split into 5 separate PNGs which are then z-indexed and absolutely positioned to create the effect of the stripe going over and under. That's pretty much all there is to it. I can edit the question if you still feel it's relevant, though.

Comment: of course it's relevant. the trick will apply to *your* code, *your* structure and *your* PNGs.

Comment: You need to share your code, so we know what you have and have no guess to bet on. `mix-blend-mode` aside `drop-shadow()` filter might do, if that is CSS used, but it's only a guess

Comment: Here it is. Like I said, it's pretty straightforward.